When pouring water into a water body, how does that form one or more vortices in the water body?
When pouring water into a water body, sometimes it forms one or more vortices and sometimes it doesn't. I know it has something to do with the conservation of angular momentum but what are the exact conditions? Sometimes they also appear in the channel so what are the conditions for that?
I was trying to understand upstream contamination and I learned the phenomenon is the most stable when two vortices appear around the jet and more so if they also appear on the channel. So when and how do they form?

Fluid dynamics is likely to be non-trivial
